# How to implement per-user views of database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a postgresql table that contains widgets and their various attributes. Each widget belongs to a group of users, but each user in the group may want to archive/hide any given widget from their view. There can be hundreds of these widgets and some users only care about some subset of them, but that becomes a per-user preference.

I'm at a loss as to how to efficiently implement this. I could include an "inactive" column on the widget table with a list of users that have hidden each row, but that seems horribly inefficient. Flipping it around so I store hidden items in a user profile doesn't seem much better as that list could get arbitrarily large over time. Are there any best practices for this sort of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a junction table.  Here is an outline:

```
create table widgets (
    widgetId serial primary key,
    . . . 
);

create table users (
    userId serial primary key,
    . . .
);

create table userWidgets (
    userWidgetId serial primary key,
    userId int not null references users(userId),
    widgetId int not null references widgets(widgetId),
    isVisible boolean
);
```